# Replace dates in data-frame column greater than reference date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` which has dates and looks like:

```
  DATE_OF_ENTRY
0    24/02/2019
1    01/08/2003
2    05/11/2002
3    03/02/2003
4    04/08/2003
5    05/02/2003
6    30/06/2003
7    01/03/2004
8    17/09/2001
```

I also have a reference date variable called `referencePeriodEndDate` which is currently equal to `'31/03/2019'`.

I am trying to change any date in the DATE_OF_ENTRY column to 'NOT KNOWN' if the date in the column is greater than the reference date.  So in the above example I would return:

```
  DATE_OF_ENTRY
0     NOT KNOWN
1    01/08/2003
2    05/11/2002
3    03/02/2003
4    04/08/2003
5    05/02/2003
6    30/06/2003
7    01/03/2004
8    17/09/2001
```

The types of the dataframe column and reference data are:

```
referencePeriodEndDate =  type <class 'str'>
DATE_OF_ENTRY =  type object
```

I have tried the following:

```
referencePeriodEndDate =  parser.parse(referencePeriodEndDate)
referencePeriodEndDate =  referencePeriodEndDate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df["DATE_OF_ENTRY"].loc[
    df["DATE_OF_ENTRY"] > referencePeriodEndDate, 
    'DATE_OF_ENTRY'
] = 'NOT KNOWN'
```

and

```
df["DATE_OF_ENTRY"] = np.where(
    df["DATE_OF_ENTRY"] > referencePeriodEndDate,
    "NOT KNOWN", df["DATE_OF_ENTRY"]
)
```

without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime()`

```
referencePeriodEndDate = pd.to_datetime('31/03/2019')
df['DATE_OF_ENTRY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_OF_ENTRY'])

df['DATE_OF_ENTRY'] = df['DATE_OF_ENTRY'].where(
    df['DATE_OF_ENTRY'] <= referencePeriodEndDate, 'NOT KNOWN'
)
```